# Selectbox is not working correctly

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, templates

What wrong with my codes?
Selectbox is not working correctly.
(Using wordpress / premium theme / trying to customize)

```
<h4><?php echo __( 'What are you?', APP_TD ); ?></h4>
<select name="role" class="form-control">
    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( HRB_ROLE_EMPLOYER ); ?>" selected="selected"><?php echo __( 'Employer', APP_TD ); ?></option>
    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( HRB_ROLE_FREELANCER ); ?>"><?php echo __( 'Freelancer', APP_TD ); ?></option>
    <?php if ( $hrb_options->share_roles_caps ): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( HRB_ROLE_BOTH ); ?>"/> <?php echo __( 'Both', APP_TD ) ?></option>
    <?php endif; ?>
</select>
```

[image: Selectbox problem]

Comment: The error could be in the code that is not in the question as of now

Comment: did you got any errors ?

Comment: It might be also just a CSS error (mistake). Try to inspect element (on the selectbox) and post the code here so we can see what does the generated html look like.